# How to run tasks in sequence?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to configure one task labeled "Build and then Run" that would execute a specific build task and then run the executable. I thought that the `dependsOn` property was what I was looking for but as it turns out it runs the tasks in parallel instead.

Here is an example of *tasks.json*:

```js
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++ -g ${workspaceFolder}/main.cpp -o ${workspaceFolder}/main.exe",
            "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
        },
        {
            "label": "Run",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${workspaceFolder}/main.exe"
        },
        {
            "label": "Build and then Run",
            "type": "shell",
            "dependsOn": [    // <------ important
                "Run",
                "Build"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It doesn't matter in what order I put the tasks into the `dependsOn` array. The "Run" task executes with error because the "Build" task creates the executable too late.

Is there some property or trick that allows two tasks to run in sequence?

Comment: `      "dependsOrder": "sequence",`  "If you specify "dependsOrder": "sequence" then your task dependencies are executed in the order they are listed in dependsOn. "  from https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_compound-tasks  It appears `parallel` is the default if you don't include this option.

Comment: @Mark Thanks. I searched literally hours for this. You can post this as an answer if you want.

Comment: Thanks, I added it as an answer.  I did a search for all `dependsOrder` questions/answers and while there were  a few how to run in parallel none were specifically how to run in sequence - although it was implied in a some they didn't help you find the answer.  Plus you would have to know the option name in the first place.  Intellisense within the task does show it to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{
   "label": "Build and then Run",
   "type": "shell",
   "dependsOrder": "sequence",    <= `parallel must be the default
   "dependsOn": [
     "Run",
     "Build"
   ]
}
```

> If you specify "dependsOrder": "sequence" then your task dependencies
> are executed in the order they are listed in dependsOn. Any
> background/watch tasks used in dependsOn with "dependsOrder":
> "sequence" must have a problem matcher that tracks when they are
> "done".

- from https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_compound-tasks

That implies to me, plus your experience, that omittiing the option `dependsOn` means by default the tasks will run in parallel, not in sequence.