# Configure Visual Studio Code task to execute multiple shell commands in sequence

Tags: json, shell, visual-studio-code, cmake, vscode-tasks

Is there a possibility, to add multiple shell commands in sequence to a Visual Studio Code task with separate arguments and options? I managed to execute multiple commands using `&&` to chain then together to a single command, as you could in any Linux shell. But i guess, there has to be a better way to do this.

I use Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Here is the example of how i currently chained the commands for a build task in a task.json file to build a c++ project using cmake:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "build",
            "command": "cd ${workspaceFolder}/build && cmake .. && make clean && make",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**Update:  -------------------------------------------------------------------**

I tried to use the `dependsOn:` property to start the 4 separatly defined tasks. However, this resulted in all 4 commands being executed at the same time in different shell instances instead of in sequence as needed:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "build project",
            "dependsOn": [
                "Go to build folder",
                "Cmake",
                "make clean",
                "make",
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Go to build folder",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cd ${workspaceFolder}/build",
            "presentation": {
                "group": "cmake-complile"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Cmake",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cmake ..",
            "presentation": {
                "group": "cmake-complile"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "make clean",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make clean",
            "presentation": {
                "group": "cmake-complile"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "make",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make",
            "presentation": {
                "group": "cmake-complile"
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configuring multiple commands in VS Code tasks (to compile and autoprefix Sass)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62945108/configuring-multiple-commands-in-vs-code-tasks-to-compile-and-autoprefix-sass)

Comment: My somewhat hacky approach would be to write a script and have VS Code execute that.

Comment: @soulshined Thanks for your suggestion. It is related, however for my build chain to work i need to execute the commands in sequence. The solution you posted executes them at the same time.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by sequence then. Would you mind elaborating? The `dependsOn` property will only run a command after a command it depends on is run, ergo, a sequence...no?.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i mean by running the commands in sequence. However, when i tried to use the ```dependsOn``` property as shown in the example you posted, it resulted in all 4 commands being executed at the same time in different terminal instances.

Comment: Maybe i just did it wrong.... i will adapt my question to make it more clear

Comment: Oh I see @Manumerous I didn’t mention the `presentation` in my answer. I think the OP did that in their question because that’s how they wanted it displayed. Try without those

Comment: You need the option: `"dependsOrder": "sequence",` as well.  Right where you have the `dependsOn` option.  Without it the default is `parallel`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62899764/836330 for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to the many comments i found a solution which works well by setting "dependsOrder" to "sequence":

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "build project",
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "dependsOn": [
                "Cmake",
                "make clean",
                "make",
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Cmake",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cmake ..",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build",
            },
        },
        {
            "label": "make clean",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make clean",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build",
            },
        },
        {
            "label": "make",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build",
            },
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```